# Different loading behavior based solely on location of app.ts file

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

This one works!  Call it **APP01**

[image]

This one doesn't work! **APP02**

[image]

Contents on the app.ts file doesn't change between the two file systems

app.ts

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})

export class TodoAppComponent {}

bootstrap(TodoAppComponent);
```

index.html  **APP01**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            //typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: { app: { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
        });

        System.import('app/app');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>

</body>
</html>
```

**APP02**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            //typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: { defaultExtension: 'js' }  <-- THIS CHANGED
        });

        System.import('app');  <-- THIS CHANGED
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>

</body>
</html>
```

So between the two in **APP02** the location of app.ts is at the root instead of in the app folder and the contents of the index.html the System.import changed from "app/app" and the packages property in the System.config.  Yet the APP02 on startup can't find teh application.  I get a error in the console of the web browser as follows.

[image]

Why does one work and the other doesn't when the only thing that changed was the location of the app.ts file.  The System.import tells the app where to find the main application where it bootstraps but it can't seem to find it in the second case it ONLY works when I put the app.ts file in the appfolder and change the System.import lines to app/app and change the packages node in the config to tell the config there is an app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import call should be to

```
System.import('app.js').then(void 0, console.error.bind(console));
```

(Added the console.error in error handler for better error catching)

The initial `.js` file import should include the extension, after that system will take over.

The APP01 version worked because of the

```
packages: { app: { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
```

which meant, everything in the folder `app` should be a `.js` file.

My assumption would be that the rest of your application will be in the `app` folder, so I would recommend that you keep this line as is.

By using

```
packages: { defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

You were actually telling System to look for a `defaultExtension` package.

Comment: So how come in the first application it only needs to be "app/app" and packages needs app for the folder but no extension need be applied to the first app for it to work.  I will try it though

Comment: ok, changing that System import line to what you indicated allowed it to find the app.js file that app.ts was transpiled to.  I'm still trying to figure out how you should organize a typical typescript/angular2 application.  It's my understanding the "packages" refer to the folders pieces of your application exist in.

Comment: one more question.  why does the application still work if I change the default extension on the app package to "ts"?  since you said it tells it the extension of what everything "should" be in the folder?  are you supposed to have your ts files in one place and have it transpiled to a different location?

Comment: By default typescript will output it's js files right beside the ts file. So the location doesn't change. When using on-the-fly transpilation as you are here, this is the "norm". However if compiling locally and then deploying only the compiled files, it is probably more "common" to have a different output location.

Comment: So because the js and ts files are side by side that's why the default extensions works in both cases?